# Integrating a density over a Mobius strip

Tags: integration, manifolds, differential-forms, mobius-band

According to [this link](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-do-a-surface-integral-on-a-mobius-strip) one can integrate over a Mobius strip by using "densities".  That has me very excited but I can't seem to find a reference on this.  Can someone provide a book/ online source that explains in detail what densities are, how they relate to regular differential forms, and shows how one can integrate over non-orientable manifolds (with boundary) with them?

Alternatively, if it wouldn't take too much effort to explain it here, that'd also work. ;)

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_on_a_manifold

Comment: This is explained in Spivak's book on differental geometry.

Comment: You mean his 5 volume set?

Answer (score 3):

You might look at Ted Frankel's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107602602), as well as [Abraham-Marsden-Ratiu](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387967907).